# Composer not updating sub-package

Tags: composer-php

Composer doesn't seem to update a sub-package for me even though it fits the dependencies and an updated version is available.

```
> c depends sub-package
  package1 requires sub-package (1.0.*)
  package2 requires sub-package (1.0.*)

> c show sub-package
  name     : sub-package
  versions : dev-master, 1.0.1, * 1.0.0

> c update
  Nothing to install or update
```

It looks like `1.0.0` is installed even though `1.0.1` meets the dependencies, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an updated version of one of the updated sub-package's sub-package (a sub-sub-package if you will) dependencies did not fit with some of my other packages.